# How to to build C++ code into both .so and .dll

Tags: c++, c, dll, .so

I am trying to find a way where I can build C/C++ code into both .dll and .so when needed. Either through Visual Studio, CMake or any other tool. I need to also need to reference third party libraries depending on which extension I'm building.

I have tried looking into CMake but it seems to build the respective extension type to your Operating System, so since I'm using Windows it seems to only build .dll and not .so.

I don't think Visual Studio can switch easily between the two especially referencing the third party .dll or .so respectively. I haven't looked at Eclipse yet.

What I am trying to do is to build a C/C++ library to be used on Android phones (which uses .so files) but I would like to test my C/C++ code my Windows PC as a sort of unit test before deploying onto the phone.

Any suggestions?

Comment: dll are shared libraries on Windows, so are shared libraries on Linux. What's the problem that you have?

Comment: Are you ok with compiling the .so and .dll on different machines?  If so, then it's probably not a big deal.  Use the correct compiler for the correct lib version.  If your goal is to have a single build system that does both, then I do that with the Autotools (libtool being the key component in this particular regard) and GCC -- the mingw-w64 on Windows.  Alternatively, this is one of CMake's specialties.

Comment: If you're looking to build both on the *same* machine, then you need both a regular and cross-compilers on the build machine, and you need to compile each library separately.  You can probably use a script or an umbrella makefile to perform a complete build of both via one command, though.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/18/android-and-ios-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/visual-cpp-for-cross-platform-mobile-development?view=vs-2017

Comment: Hi John, would you know how to use Cmake to build either dll or so on the same machine, is it just a case of using the respective C/C++ compilers?